# Problems converting code to Swift from obj-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Im trying to convert to swift code, which sets files property to "not to backup to iCloud"

Original code looks like this

```
- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtPath:(NSString *) filePathString {
   NSURL* URL= [NSURL fileURLWithPath: filePathString];
   assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]]);

   NSError *error = nil;
   BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
                              forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];
   if(!success){
    NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);
    }
    return success;
 }
```

I came with the such code

```
func addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL(URL: NSURL) -> Bool{

   let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
   assert(fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(URL.absoluteString))

   var error:NSError?
   let success:Bool = try? URL.setResourceValue(NSNumber(bool: true),forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey)

   if !success {
    print("Error excluding \(URL.lastPathComponent) from backup \(error)")
   } else {
    print("File at path \(URL) was succesfully updated")
   }

   return success
   }
```

but it throws error at line with `let success:Bool`

> Cannot convert value of type '()?' to specified type 'Bool'

How to fix that ?

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. If the given answers are not satisfying, ask the author for clarification, or *edit* your question to provide additional information.

Answer (score 3):

[setResourceValue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/setResourceValue:forKey:error:) is not returning a `Bool` to indicate the success, but throws an error when it fails. So you should wrap it in a `try catch` block.

̶W̶e̶l̶l̶,̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶d̶o̶c̶u̶m̶e̶n̶t̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶l̶o̶o̶k̶s̶ ̶o̶u̶t̶d̶a̶t̶e̶d̶, the docs describes error handling in Swift at the bottom, but if you jump it's defenition, you would see that the method does not return anything:

```
public func setResourceValue(value: AnyObject?, forKey key: String) throws
```

Comment: Thanks! Maybe is there another way I can check file property if it was set successfully ?

Comment: @AlexeyK Yes, of course, if it throws, it wasn't successful. If it doesn't throw, it was successful.

Comment: Welcome! And for the other question, I don't know if there is another way.

Comment: And "throws" is going to stay in Swift, so you better learn how to use it as quickly as possible. Don't even bother to find a different call, because _lots_ of calls will throw in Swift 2.